# Why does a program containing only of simple singleton class does not fit in flash memory of my STM32F030?

Tags: c++, exception, gcc, arm, stm32

I wanted to refactor my object used for storing the system time in milliseconds for my STM32F030 project to a singleton pattern (it was just normal a global object before). I did it and to my surprise,  the linker cannot link the code anymore, because it wouldn't fit in my flash memory nor in RAM (I've had plenty of free space before). Why is it happening? My suspicion is that the GCC compiler adds a ton of excpetion-handling code, but I don't understand why would it happen.

I'm using the G++ provided with the System Workbench for STM32 IDE. 
I decided to strip the code down to the smallest non-working snippet and found out that the code bloat happens whenever there's a static class method that returns a reference or object of this class AND there's an explicit constructor for this class (even if it's just a declaration with empty body). Funnily enough, if I remove the constructor and let the compiler provide the constructor for me, the code bloat disappears. It doesn't matter whether the constructor is public or private.

```cpp
class Singleton {
public:
    //if I remove the next line the project links!
    Singleton(){}
    static Singleton& instance() {
        static Singleton singleton;
        return singleton;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    auto temp = Singleton::instance();
    for(;;) {

    }
}
```

As you can see, the program does nothing at all, except from lazily initializing the singleton instance, so the code should be as small as possible.
I'm compiling the code with `-fno-exceptions`, `-fno-rtti`, `-Oz` optimizations and still get the following result:

`` /../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: test.elf section `.text' will not fit in region `FLASH'
/../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: region `FLASH' overflowed by 12012 bytes ``

I'm suspecting GCC adds exception-handling calls, because a similar thing happened to me before (declaring a function pure virtual also increased the code size by ~50kB), but maybe I'm missing something. Is there any way around this problem?

**EDIT**: Following the suggestion from the comments I've edited the linker script by increasing flash size so that the program would link. Here's the relevant part of the generated map file: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/FKf8AnCa)

It seems, that there really is some exception handling inserted into the generated code (unwind calls, `___Unwind_RaiseException`, `__cxa_allocate_exception`, `__cxa_throw` `std::exception::~exception()` and so on).

I was thinking this may be a compiler-specific issue, so I compiled the code with ARMCLANG provided by Keil IDE, and the result code size was less than 1kB.

**EDIT 2**:
I found a solution to the code-bloat issue (passing `-fno-threadsafe-statics` flag to the compiler greatly reduces code size), but it comes at the cost of thread safety. The project I'm working on is not single-threaded as it uses interrupts, so I guess I will just go with the explicitly initialized global variable approach that I started with.

**EDIT 3**:
It seems that the static initialization thread-safety code bloat was just a symptom of a problem, and the real culprit was the *Newlib* library, which is an implementation of standard C/C++ library for embedded systems. Using a *newlib-nano* instead of standard *newlib* greatly reduces code size (now the cost of thread safe static initialization is only a dozen or so bytes, instead of the previous 70kB). One can enable the *newlib-nano* by passing the `--specs=nano.specs` flag to the linker.

Comment: If your compiler is C++11 compliant, static class variables must now be made thread-safe automatically by the compiler.

Comment: Static initialisation requires runtime logic to work properly. Not sure why you think it's exception related when you disable exceptions.

Comment: If you're concerned about introducing possible exceptions try adding `noexcept` to the constructor. Note that `temp` makes a copy of `Singleton`, and the copy constructor is not deleted. So it's not really singleton. It may also be that the "only constructed once" requirement of `static` forces the introduction of threading primitives which might contribute to code bloat.

Comment: You can see the code behind the threadsafe initialiser over at [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/_eEFox).  Comment out the constructor and it disappears, although I'm not sure why.

Comment: Post your map file on pastebin and put the link in your post.

Comment: tell the linker you have more flash/ram than you have to the point that it passes, then look at the map file, readelf, objdump -D and examine those to see what has blown out your size.  being C++ and i assume built against chip libraries there is probably a lot more code than you think behind this.  but by adding and removing and examining what that does to the overall binary you can perhaps figure this out

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/UULztQ -- maybe, pointers will help?
No thread-safe guards, I guess you don't need them, right?

Comment: @Cubic I was thinking it was a static initialization issue, but as the godbolt link shows, it looks like it should add a few extra instructions, not over 70kB of code.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux adding noexcept to the constructor doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @JacekŚlimok I edited the question by posting the link to the relevant part of the map file, and it really does look like there are exceptions involved in the output code.

Comment: @balkers I would just go with the bare-bones, thread-unsafe, pointer version of the singleton if what you're building is a single-threaded app.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie unfortunately I cannot use this version, because dynamic memory allocation is a no-no in this project. I found a solution to the code-bloat issue (passing `-fno-threadsafe-statics` flag to the compiler greatly reduces code size), but it comes at the cost of thread safety. The project I'm working on is not single-threaded as it uses interrupts, so I guess I will just go with the explicitly initialized global variable approach that I started with.

Comment: This case unfortunately demonstrates that c++ is not ready for small embedded systems. At least not yet. As soon as a developer wants to show off and fly their "object oriented" skills, productivity is destroyed and they waste time instead of doing useful work.